# Как в pytest проверить, что код вызывает исключение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Имеется код, в котором функция `num2tuple` с аргументом `'(17,'` должна выдавать `SyntaxError`. Как это можно оформить с pytest?

```py
def test_num2tuple():
    assert num2tuple('(17,') == SyntaxError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы проверить, что код вызывает исключение, нужно использовать менеджер контекста `pytest.raises`:

```
import pytest

def test_num2tuple():
    with pytest.raises(SyntaxError):
        num2tuple('(17,')
```

Если функция не выбросит исключение, будет такая картина:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.1.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /home/insolor/stackoverflow
collected 1 item                                                               

pytst.py F                                                               [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_num2tuple ________________________________

    def test_num2tuple():
        with pytest.raises(SyntaxError):
>           num2tuple('(17,')
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'SyntaxError'>

pytst.py:11: Failed
============================== 1 failed in 0.05s ===============================
```